# Slowly Sliding Page Background Image

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I am trying to make a suttle effect using the background image. I am trying to make it move very slowly to the left then stop once the whole image has been seen.

At the moment the image does not move at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
body
{
width:100%;
height:100px;
top:0;
background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Yercaud_scenery.jpg');
position:relative;
-webkit-animation:mymove 4s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
}


@-webkit-keyframes mymove /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {top:0px;left:-70px;}
25%  {top:0px;left:-50px;}
75%  {top:0px;left:30px;}
100% {top:0px;left:31px}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>here is some sample text</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am not bound to only using css but would prefer if possible.

Comment: Have you tried it closing the style tag with </style> instead of </script>?

Comment: @RickCalder sorry it is closed on production. my own typo when reporting the issue.

Comment: Where do you define the "move" animation? You have to use `@keyframes` http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/17/an-introduction-to-css3-keyframe-animations/

Comment: @Miszy I see how keyframes can be added but can I define it for the body tag or do they have to be specific to an element?

Comment: @Miszy updated the above code - seems the elements on the page only scroll not the background image - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using keyframes through css I wanted something lighter and simpler.  I have seemed to have found a solution involving the use of a few lines of jquery & css.

The Javascript:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("body").animate({backgroundPositionX : "-450"}, 25000);
});
</script>
```

The CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    background-image: url('../imgs/bg-image.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    }
</style>
```